# How to customize the generated QR code like the images below

Tags: android, kotlin, qr-code, zxing

[image]

[image]

I'm developing a QR generator android application.
I want to change my QR code theme like the images that are given below. Help me out to customize the source for the encoder.

Comment: zxing's `MultiFormatWriter` can give you a `BitMatrix`, where each element represents whether it should be plotted as a black pixel or a white pixel. But you can of course implement a different plotting routine that draws one bitmap for "on" and another for "off". How you do that is entirely up to you.

Comment: @Ghayas, have you got any solution for this?

Comment: @RahulMishra No, I didn't find anything about it.